# React Native Map Marker does NOT maintain the color assigned to it

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, maps, react-native-maps

I have 85 Locations in a list . Each location has a status of **maybe** , **yes** , or **no**. where

Yes = **Green** pin color

No = **Red** pin color

Maybe = **Orange** pin color

Whenever I tap on a certain marker, its color will change to green. then if I tap on the map, the color will go back to whatever its suppose to be. Sometimes the markers render with the wrong color too. it's starting to get very frustrating due to the fact that such a simple task is yet so complex in this accomplish in this framework.

**This is my code :**

```
const get_color = (v) => {
    switch (v.stop_status) {
        case 'yes':
            return `green`

        case 'maybe':
            return `orange`

        case 'no':
            return `red`
    }
}

<MapView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                region={{
                    latitude: 31.594,
                    longitude: -102.74,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.015 * 4000,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.015 * 4000,
                }}
                showsUserLocation={true}
            >
                {crossings.length != 0
                    ? crossings.map((l, i) => (
                          <Marker
                              key={i}
                              pinColor={get_color(l.stop_status)}
                              coordinate={{
                                  latitude: parseFloat(l.stop_latitude),
                                  longitude: parseFloat(l.stop_longitude),
                              }}
                              title={l.stop_name}
                          />
                      ))
                    : null}
            </MapView>
```

Any help would be very appreciated